# How do I graph a line in Julia with an arrow on both sides?

Tags: julia

Here is my code:

```
using MTH229
using Plots
f(x)=x
theme(:dark)
plot(f,-5,5,linewidth=5,c=:hotpink,legend=false,arrow=true)
```

Here is a picture of the output:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGsgV.png)

How do I get the arrow to appear on both ends of the line instead of just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot` and `plot!` commands have an arrow parameter that in turn has a special option `:both` to have arrows on both ends. Hence you can just do

```
plot(f,-5,5,linewidth=5,c=:hotpink,legend=false,
     arrow=Plots.Arrow(:open, :both, 2.5, 2.0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this looks like a better answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hacky solution, but for the example in the question:

```
plot!([-4.99,-5],[f(-4.99), f(-5)],
  linewidth=5,c=:hotpink,legend=false,arrow=true)
```

adds the reverse arrow. Generalizing to any chart is pretty straight forward. The idea is to draw a line chart with a reverse direction, for just a tiny bit at the location of the reverse arrow and let Plot add the reverse arrow.

[image: Chart with reverse arrow]

Comment: no need for hacking - use the `arrow` parameter (see my answer)